# My .exe file is considered as threat on other computers .. Why?

Tags: java, exe, antivirus

I have a Java program .exe that is on my web site ..

it's a simple program that ask questions and answers .. it's safe if any one download it

but if my friends try to download it their antiviruses say "Threat has been detected"

is there any thing I can do to make it much safer to download it?

Thanks,

EDIT: Here's a screenshot of my program ..

actually it's written in Jess running from a Java class that has main method

http://img706.imageshack.us/img706/1710/quizj.png

Comment: For starters, you could make sure it's a *false* positive.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try uploading your file to https://www.virustotal.com/. If many virus scanners are saying it is infected, then it surely is and you should search your computer for an infection by doing a hard(!) poweroff (so not virus shutdown hooks can be executed) and then use a live cd to scan your hard drive.

Otherwise it's just a false alarm. What does your application do? Can you provide a screenshot or a detailed error message?

Comment: what do you by "you should search your computer for an infection by doing a hard(!) poweroff (so not virus shutdown hooks can be executed) and then use a live cd to scan your hard drive"?!

Comment: In case your computer would've been infected somehow, the malware could watch for created exe files to infect them, too. What are the results from the virustotal analysis?

Comment: I've scanned my computer no viruses showed! but may be u r right .. my computer these days is acting weird .. is it gonna make difference if rebuild it from another computer that has high protection?

Comment: Malware programmers always try to hide from any virus software and anti-virus vendors are lagging behind a bit because they have to analyse the malware first. Ask someone else to create a live CD, e.g. http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desinfec%E2%80%99t Maybe you can also try hijackthis: http://www.trendmicro.com/ftp/products/hijackthis/HiJackThis.msi

Comment: The MD5 checksum of the current HiJackThis should be e26bbfd430b526c4ca7e4e7c08c96fb2 Verify it is the same.

Answer (score 1):

I am reacting to

> is there any thing I can do to make it much safer to download it

You could use an applet or better use Java Web Start to distribute your Java application take a look at the [Webstart Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/index.html)

Comment: thanks .. actually I was trying to make it as an applet but there is no time left for me .. it's a project that need to be submitted in one week! :)

Comment: then use Java Web Start, it is really easy(!) You will just create a little jnlp file and need to have the jars of the application available for download.

Comment: I did it .. but I'm having problems now .. could you please go to this page http://stackoverflow.com/q/10644057/1365041